# How can I checked that SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback) works fine?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have used Google Maps API v2 in an Android project. SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync () is used to get a google Map instance and represents it in your Activity. When the map is ready, a callback to OnMapReadyCallback.onMapReady (GoogleMaps) is done. But, no exception is raised. How could i check that getMapAsync really worked? Because sometimes, the map returned is empty.

Comment: If an error happens while loading the map you can see it in logcat

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler Yeah, but i'd like to treat it programatically